# Pass few variables using GET and dynamic HTML

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I would like create hyperlink with few variables and pass to another php file

```
echo "<td><a href='content/add.php?code=".$row['code']."?age=".$row['age']."'>"Edit"</a></td>";
```

but when i trying read in php file:

```
$code = $_GET['code'];
$age = $_GET['age'];
```

Only one variable have beed transfered $code but with `?age=37`.How to transfer multiple variables?

Comment: Change `?age=` to `&age=`, `?` is just for the first var, `&` to other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
content/add.php?code=".$row['code']."?variable2...
```

should be

```
content/add.php?code=".$row['code']."&variable2...
```

The char defining the start of the `GET` arguments is `?`, then the arguments are sparated with the char `&`.

Answer (score 1):

You separate the parameters with ? from the URI, but with & from other parameters. So you need :

```
echo "<td><a href='content/add.php?code=".$row['code']."&age=".$row['age']."'>"Edit"</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

the best practice is using a form

`<form action ="content/add.php" method="get">
    <input name="age" type = "hidden" value="37"/>
    <input name="code" type = "hidden" value ="your_value/>"
    <input name = "submit" type="submit" value ="edit"
</form>`

then the values woll be passed to you php script